# Mode of the difference of two beta distributions

Tags: distributions, group-differences, beta-distribution, differences

Given two beta distributions $X \sim \beta(m_1, n_1)$ and $Y \sim \beta(m_2, n_2)$, how to compute the mode of the distribution of $Z = X - Y$?

Comment: Could be of help:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/192716/distribution-of-differences-in-beta-distribution