# Distribution of differences in beta-distribution

Tags: beta-distribution, order-statistics, extreme-value

I want to get an analytic solution to the difference of the highest and second highest of a beta distribution.

More simply, I have some datapoints on which I assume a beta-distribution. Analytically I can get a cumulative distribution $F_n(x)$ over the maximum of a sample of size $n$ from the original cumulative distribution $F(x)$:

$F_n(x) = P(X_n < x) = F(x)^n$

But now I want to get a distribution over the difference between the highest and second highest from a sample. Is there a way to do it?

If I use a sampling solution I get distributions like this (not normalized):
[image: Histogram of differences between highest and second highest sample of betadistribution]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the joint density of $(X_{(n-1)},X_{(n)})$ the two largest observation, [their joint density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic#The_joint_distribution_of_the_order_statistics_of_an_absolutely_continuous_distribution) is given by 
$$g_n(x,y)=\dfrac{n!}{(n-2)!0!0!}F(x)^{n-2}[F(y)-F(x)]^0[1-F(y)]^0f(x)f(y)\mathbb{I}_{x\le y}$$
(where the $0$'s are considering the special case $j=n-1$, $k=n$ [in the generic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic#The_joint_distribution_of_the_order_statistics_of_an_absolutely_continuous_distribution)).

From there the derivation of the distribution of the difference $Z_{n}=(X_{(n)}-X_{(n-1)})$ is a mere convolution formula, i.e. a special case of a change of variables:
$$\begin{align}Z_n\sim&\int_\mathcal{X} g_n(x,x+z)\, \text{d}x\ \mathbb{I}_{(0,\infty)}(z)\\
&=n(n-1)\,\int_\mathcal{X} F(x)^{n-2}f(x)f(x+z)\, \text{d}x\ \mathbb{I}_{(0,\infty)}(z)
\end{align}$$
In the special case of a Beta $\mathfrak{B}(a,b)$ distribution, $F=F(\cdot;a,b)$ has no analytic expression in general, so you get
$$n(n-1)B(a,b)^{-2}\,\int_0^{1-z} F(x;a,b)^{n-2}x^{a-1}(1-x)^{b-1}(x+z)^{a-1}(1-x-z)^{b-1}\, \text{d}x\ \mathbb{I}_{(0,1}(z)$$

Comment: I didn't follow your comment that, in the case of a Beta distribution, the cdf $F$ has no analytic expression.  The cdf of a Beta random variable is $$\frac{B_x(a,b)}{B(a,b)}$$ where the numerator is the incomplete Beta function.

Comment: Might also be worth checking the above for typos, with a simple example. For example, with a = 1, b = 3 and n=2, the above does not appear to integrate to unity.

Comment: @wolfies: (a) it all depends how you define $B(a,b)$; (b) if replacing $F(x;a,b)$ with $B_x(a,b)$ makes the integral analytically computable for non-integer values of $(a,b)$, thanks for letting us know.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, that -2 (instead of +2) made things work. I checked with some arbitrary values and the pdf seems right. I just used a discretization of the interval.

Comment: But with the expression for a cdf of the beta distribution, is there a solution that does not need discretization of the integral? Would make things much faster.